# ¿Se puede crear un evento que desencadene otro evento en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos, jframe, jlabel

[image: Imagen Con los Objetos del proyexto]estoy programando el juego piedra papel o tijera en java, y quería dar la posibilidad de que se pueda jugar de a dos personas, pero cuando tengo todos los eventos programados para una, y por ejemplo si el usuario elige dos personas en lugar de una quería saber si hay alguna forma en la que pueda primero detectar si un label se presiono y luego en ese mismo evento se llame a otro para guardar el valor que se genero al presionar el label.

Edit: En la imagen tengo la opción "2 jugadores" el cual es un botón, que me gustaría que cuando se pulse por el usuario se pueda registrar la opción que elija el primer jugador(correspondiente a las imágenes de la derecha), y luego se puedan elegir la opcion que el segundo usuario quiera(correspondiente a las imágenes de la izquierda), y luego se compararan ambas elecciones en las cuales veremos el ganador.
**Código Del evento que se dispara al pulsar 1 Jugador**

```
private void btnChooseOnePlayer1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    btnChooseTwoPlayer.hide();
    btnChooseOnePlayer1.hide();
    jLabelChooseOption.setVisible(true);
    labelDecisionSecondUser.setVisible(true);
    labelPaperOne.setVisible(true);
    labelScissorOne.setVisible(true);
    labelRockOne1.setVisible(true);
    onePlayer = true;
}                           

**Ejemplo de codigo que se ejecuta si la persona para jugar contra la pc elige la piedra**


    private void labelRockOne1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    controladorOpcionUsuario.setHand(Hand.PIEDRA);
     //System.out.println("La decision del usuario ha sido"+ controladorOpcionUsuario.getHand().getIndex());
     if(onePlayer== true){
         //Definiremos un rango en el cual se ejecutara el modulo random 
         Integer min_value = 0;
         Integer max_value = 3;
         Random ran = new Random();
         comoputerChoice = ran.nextInt(max_value) + min_value;
         System.out.println(comoputerChoice);
         if(comoputerChoice == 0){
             controller controladorComputadora = new controller();
             controladorComputadora.setHand(Hand.PIEDRA);
             jLabelResult.setText("EMPATEI!!");
             jPanelScreen.setBackground(Color.yellow);
             System.out.println("Tu eleccion fue:"+ controladorOpcionUsuario.getHand()+ "Eleccion del PC:" + controladorComputadora.getHand());
         }else if(comoputerChoice == 1){
             //System.out.println("ELIGIO PAPEL LA PC");
             controller controladorComputadora = new controller();
             controladorComputadora.setHand(Hand.PAPEL);
             jLabelResult.setText("PERDISTE, SIGUE INTENTANDO!!");
             jPanelScreen.setBackground(Color.red);
             System.out.println("Tu eleccion fue:"+ controladorOpcionUsuario.getHand()+ "Eleccion del PC:" + controladorComputadora.getHand());
         }else if(comoputerChoice == 2){
             //System.out.println("ELIGIO TIJERA LA PC");
             controller controladorComputadora = new controller();
             controladorComputadora.setHand(Hand.TIJERA);
             jLabelResult.setText("GANASTE, CONTINUA ASI!!");
             jPanelScreen.setBackground(Color.green);
             System.out.println("Tu eleccion fue:"+ controladorOpcionUsuario.getHand()+ "Eleccion del PC:" + controladorComputadora.getHand());
         }
     }  
    
}
```

**Clase Principal/Hand donde estan todos los objetos piedra,papel,tijera**

```
public enum Hand {
PIEDRA(0),
PAPEL(1),
TIJERA(2);

private Integer index;

private Hand(Integer index){
    this.index = index;
}

public Integer getIndex() {
    return index;
}

public void setIndex(Integer index) {
    this.index = index;
}
```

}

Comment: Vas a necesitar ser más específico... hay algo que te impida llamar a una función ahí?

Comment: Disculpa mi imprecisión con las palabras, espero que se entienda mejor asi, muchas gracias. Lo que quería hacer era que cuando se pulse por el usuario se pueda registrar la opción que elija el primer jugador (correspondiente a las imágenes de la derecha), y luego se puede elegir la opción que el segundo usuario quiera (correspondiente a las imágenes de la izquierda), y luego se compararan ambas elecciones en las cuales veremos el ganador.

Comment: Y ya intentaste definir callbacks mediante el uso de Function?